# Excel VBA Macro Mysterious Slow down

Tags: excel, vba

### The Problem:

From July to Now, it slowed from very fast to impossibly slow (5 seconds or less to 30 Minutes +).

I copied the whole code base to an old File from Juni and it wasn't slow any more.

Code changed mostly superficial.
The first time I noticed a slowdown was in July.
Now it was so slow it stopped working. After pasting the code to an old file, the slowdown is gone, but I would like to know what caused this and how to prevent this in the future.

### Description of what it does

It's a sort of calendar with multiple machines that covers one week and sorts their activity into categories to generate a report.

First it loads Name, Description, and 2 Timestamps (for start and end) from 7 days (every day machines create a report). I built a small graphical interface to Automate most of the inputs for the User. 
These data entries are saved in rows and need to be cleaned to have only valid entries. After that it loads data from 2 other sources to complete the dataset. There will be a lot of overlap here, the automatic execution of a "pruning" algorithm is the main point of this File.

After that the user has a pivot table and multiple tables to make holes and mistakes (inside the Calendar) visible and prepare a report.

Its normal to have about 450 entries per week.
A lot of the macros get executed multiple times.
My laptop on which I execute this code should handle the load:
I7 4600U + 8GB RAM
The files that I take the data from are located on a network drive.

### Things I have tried:

- I looked at ways to speed up the code and re-wrote most of the [mistakes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23849267).
- I added a garbage collection for Queries and Connections and deleted old named ranges.
- writing a function to disable unnecessary work while executing
- Scanning the code for slowdowns

### Things I have observed:

- The new file has a RAM usage of 280 MB and it goes up to 900MB while executing a macro.
- The old file with new code has a RAM usage of 90 MB and it goes up to 100MB while executing .
- I suspect it somehow gets stuck in endless loops of copying data, because of the slow climb to extreme RAM usage. But why would it be fine in a new file?

### Code Examples:

I found this particular part sometimes needed up to 10 Minutes:
This code Part is critical to limit the number of times my macro has to execute.

```
 '##################################Custom sort 
With Sheets("Knopf_Cronjob").sort
    With .SortFields
        .clear 'Sorts on three Values, Machine Name, Start time and End time
        .Add Key:=Range("C2:C" & lgletzte), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("E2:E" & lgletzte), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("F2:F" & lgletzte), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    .SetRange Range("A1:R" & lgletzte)
    .Header = xlYes
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

This part also takes around 5-10 minutes sometimes:

```
 For Row = lgletzte To 2 Step -1
        'iterates the whole sheet to look for Monday and saturday,
        ' to cut the Time around 6 a clock and split into two Entrys
        weekday1 = Weekday(.Cells(Row, 5), vbMonday)

        If weekday1 = 1 Or weekday1 = 6 Then
            'Column 5 is the Start time, Column 6 the End Time
            'this looks for Start times before 6 a clock and End Times after 6  a clock
            If (.Cells(Row, 5) - Int(Sheets("Knopf_Cronjob").Cells(Row, 5))) < 0.25 And _
                                                                             (.Cells(Row, 6) - Int(.Cells(Row, 6))) > 0.25 Then
                .Rows(Row).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Knopf_Cronjob").Rows(lgletzte + 1) 'Copies to new Row
                .Cells(lgletzte + 1, 5).Value2 = 0.25 + Int(.Cells(Row, 5))
                'sets the Split time to 6 a clock
                .Cells(Row, 6).Value2 = 0.25 + Int(.Cells(Row, 6))
                lgletzte = lgletzte + 1          'adds 1 to the last row
            End If
        End If
    Next Row
End With
```

I don`t think these code snippets are the problem in particular.

This is the macro that inserts one day of data:
Usually this executes in a around a second but lately it takes 2-5 Minutes.

```
Sheets("last_day_status").Activate
With ActiveSheet.Cells 'Clears the place holder sheet for the New Data
    .clear
    .ClearContents
End With


'################################## Reading last_day_status
'Change Path here
'***********************************************************************************************************************************
On Error GoTo 404 'routine to catch if the File isn´t found
Sheets("last_day_status").Range("A1").Select
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "path" & d & "_last_day_status.csv", _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
'***********************************************************************************************************************************


Dim b As Long
Dim c As Date

b = Sheets("last_day_status").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row 'b is the last row that contains Data

c = d - 1 'c is one day before the given Date
'In Format "M/T/JJJJ"
Dim x1 As Integer
Dim x2 As Integer
Dim x3 As Integer
Dim Datum As String
Dim tag As String
Dim monat As String
Dim jahr As String

'############################
'day
x1 = InStr(1, c, ".")
tag = Mid(c, 1, x1 - 1)

'Month
x2 = InStr(x1 + 1, c, ".")
monat = Mid(c, x1 + 1, x2 - x1 - 1)

'Year
x3 = Len(c) + 2
jahr = Mid(c, x2 + 1, x3 - x2)

If Len(tag) > 1 Then
x1 = InStr(1, tag, "0")
tag = Mid(tag, x1 + 1, Len(tag))
End If

If Len(monat) > 1 Then
x2 = InStr(1, monat, "0")
monat = Mid(monat, x2 + 1, Len(monat))
End If

Datum = monat & "/" & tag & "/" & jahr


'Filters out only maschines that are Activity Tracked
'***********************************************************************************************************************************
xxx
'*************************************************************************************************************************************

'################################## Copies Data to Mainsheet
a = Sheets("last_day_status").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row 'b is the last row that contains Data


Sheets("last_day_status").Range(Cells(65536, 3).End(xlUp), Cells(2, 7)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    Sheets("Knopf_Cronjob").Range("C" & a) 'Copies Data
Sheets("Knopf_Cronjob").Activate

Dim lgletzte As Long
Dim lgcount As Long

a = 0
With Sheets("Knopf_Cronjob")
lgletzte = .Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("E2:F" & lgletzte).NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm" 'formates the Time Columns

For lgcount = lgletzte To 2 Step -1

'################################## Deletes Times before the given Week
    If .Cells(lgcount, 6) < Int(.Cells(1, 12)) Then 'end before Monday = Delete
        .Rows(lgcount).Delete
    End If
    If .Cells(lgcount, 5) < Int(.Cells(1, 12)) Then '
        If .Cells(lgcount, 6) > Int(.Cells(1, 12)) Then 'Cuts of start to Start of the week
            .Cells(lgcount, 5).Value2 = Int(.Cells(1, 12))
    Else
            .Rows(lgcount).Delete
            lgcount = lgcount - 1
        End If

    End If
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'##################################Deletes Times after the given Week
    If .Cells(lgcount, 6) > Int(.Cells(1, 13)) Then
        If .Cells(lgcount, 5) < Int(.Cells(1, 13)) Then
            .Cells(lgcount, 6) = Int(.Cells(1, 13))
        Else
            .Rows(lgcount).Delete
            lgcount = lgcount - 1
        End If
    End If


'################# Sorts the activity Name into Groups
    Dim typename As String
    typename = .Cells(lgcount, 4).Value 'column 4 is the Activity Column
    Select Case typename
    Case "Pretest"
        .Cells(lgcount, 7).Value = "Test" ' Column 7 is reserved for comments
        .Cells(lgcount, 4).Value = "Test"
    Case "Test"
        .Cells(lgcount, 4).Value = "TEST"
    Case "Wait"
        .Cells(lgcount, 4).Value = "WAIT"
    End Select
Next lgcount
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


'Deletes times that are close to Midnight
lgletzte = .Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
For lgcount = lgletzte To 2 Step -1
    If .Cells(lgcount, 5) - Int(.Cells(lgcount, 5)) <= 0.0001 Then
        .Cells(lgcount, 5).Value2 = Int(.Cells(lgcount, 5))
    End If
    If .Cells(lgcount, 6) - Int(.Cells(lgcount, 6)) <= 0.0001 Then
        .Cells(lgcount, 6).Value2 = Int(.Cells(lgcount, 6)) - 0.0000116
    End If

Next lgcount
End With
```

The problem also is that this slowdown effects every macro.

Comment: As I understand it, you have functional code that runs too slowly. If that's the case, this would be a much better fit for [CodeReview.se] than it would be for here. I'd suggest you take a look over there, read up on the posting guidelines and post there instead. You'll get a pretty thorough review and there are a lot of folks with seriously in-depth VBA knowledge.